# Can't install latest angular cli on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I'm trying to install angular via ubuntu.

When I type the version commande `node -v`

I get `v12.14.1`

Then I try to install npm package `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

I get a warning

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.15.2

`ng version`

I get `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3`

The npm version is `6.13.4`

Comment: What happens on `sudo node -v`

Comment: using sudo I have 10.15.2, but how can I install one node version ? I'm the only one user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that `sudo node -v` gives 10.15.2 where as `node -v` gives 12.14.1.

This means that there are 2 different node versions installed.

You can get around this by using `sudo -E node -v` or by deleting the link to the other node.js install by doing: `rm /usr/local/bin/node`.